# Is the subset $\{f_n: n\geq 0\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, independence

For each non-negative integer $n$, let $f_n\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $f_n$: $x\to \sin^n(x)$. Is the subset $\{f_n: n\geq 0\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ linearly independent.

So I did an induction proof for this. However, I feel that this is the incorrect method for a problem like this because we need to show that any subset of the following form is linearly independent. How can I show that this set is linearly independent? Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Base case: When $n=0$ we have $\sin^0(x)=1$ and a linear combination of a non-zero vector is always L.I.. So the base case is satisfied. Assume the result holds for some $k<n$ and consider a linear combination of $k+1$ vectors. That is, $c_0\sin^0(x)+c_s\sin(x)+\cdots + c_k\sin^k(x)+c_{k+1}\sin^{k+1}(x)=0$. By the induction hypothesis the first k terms are L.I.. So the constants are all zero and it follows that $c_{k+1}=0$ and the set is L.I.

Comment: If you mean that you proved $S_N=\{f_n; 0\le n\le N\}$ is linearly independent then this suffices. Any linear combination belongs to $\text{span}S_N$ for some $N$.

Comment: I don't think I did exactly that. I posted what I did. I feel like it is wrong.

Comment: Your argument is wrong.  You take $f_0,\ldots f_n$ are indipendent by hypothesis. This means that $c_0f_0+\ldots+c_kf_k=0$ implies $c_0=\ldots =c_k=0$. Instead you have $c_0f_0+\ldots+c_kf_k=-c_{k+1}f_{k+1}$. This not imply $c_0=\ldots =c_k=0$. So your induction argument doesn't work.

Comment: ok, can induction be used to prove this result?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose, by contradiction, that there exist $M>0$ and real coefficients $a_0,a_1,\ldots a_M$, not all equal to $0$, such that
$$\sum_{n=0}^Ma_n\sin^n{x}\equiv 0\qquad\mbox{(*)}$$
Now $\sin{x}$ assumes all values in $[-1,1]$, in particular it assumes $M+1$ distinct values $\alpha_0,\ldots\alpha_{M}$. Imposing that (*) holds for all those values of $\sin{x}$, we get that the vector $a=(a_0,a_1,\ldots a_n)$ satisfies
$Va=0$, where $V$ is a Vandermonde matrix with coefficients $\alpha_0,\ldots\alpha_{M}$. Since these values are all distinct, $\det{V}\neq 0$, and so we get $a=0$, absurd.